# Display "K" as thousands and "M" for milions Excel

Tags: excel, custom-formatting

What I'd like to do is display in XLS custom format for both thousands and millions in the same time, with keeping all the values below 1000 normally. With one number after coma. So:

- 100 = 100,0
- 1000 = 1,0K
- 1000000 = 1,0M
- 1500 = 1,5K
  and so on..

What I've got so far is:

```
[<1000]0;[>=1000]# ###,0 "M";[>=1000000]#"MM";0
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Note: for my country space works as a thousand separator and comma as decimal

Answer (score 1):

The following format should format the numbers according to your requirements:

```
[<1000]#,0;[<1000000]#\ ###,0."K";#\ ###,##0.."M"
```

Note how dots are used to indicate the number should be divided by 1000 or 1000000 for display formatting. However, take note that I have Excel running under Latin-American Spanish localization, and I'm not sure if those should always be dots or should follow your localized thousands separator.

Also, be aware that under this format negative numbers will always follow the "<1000" format as the "less than 1000" rule is fulfilled.

Answer (score -2):

You can make a custom format for your cell.
number->custom 
apply this format: 0.K
for thousands